# R- How do you jump ahead to a specific index of a loop when debugging in the browser?

Tags: r

I'm trying to jump ahead 40 iterations within a loop in the browser instead of repeatedly pressing n. How?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really jump ahead a certain number of iterations in the browser. It might be better to star the browser after a certain number of iterations have already passed. You can set a conditional breakpoint with `trace()`. For example

```
test<-function(x) {
    for(i in 1:x) {
        print(i)
    }
}

trace(test, at=list(c(2,4)), tracer=quote(if (i==3) browser()))
test(10)
```

This will trigger the browser when `i==3`.

Or you can just add a conditional into the function

```
test<-function(x) {
    for(i in 1:x) {
        if(i==3) browser()
        print(i)
    }
}
```

More information [here](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/debug.shtml#dbgcond)